# How to copy a framework to myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm using a framework, PGSQLKit.framework in my application, it's inside the project and also inside the 'Link Binary With Libraries' part of the build phases and works fine on my machine.

For giving the program away, to people don't having the PGQQLKit.framework installed, at the moment I first `mkdir 'myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks'` and then copy the PGQQLKit.framework manually into  myApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/ which works, but needs to be done any time I do a fresh build.

Any Xcode4 gurus knowing the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add a Copy Files build phase to your application's target. Move it above the Link phase, set its destination to Frameworks, and add the framework to it.